# SQlite3 — SQL datetime stamps

Tags: datetime, sqlite

Am I right in thinking that SQL does intrinsically store a date/time stamp for each commit? i.e., that I have to allow for recording this information as part of my schema design?

It will take a certain amount of space to store this information explicitly (using `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or my own timestamp), and if there's a way of accessing comparable information in some internal database setting, I'd do that instead. I'm working with SQLite3 at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not have any internal time stamps.
(SQLite [database files](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html) do not even have any record of transaction once they are committed.)